# How to call 2 methods of a struct in parallel which are async , using lilos

Tags: rust, async-await

I am trying to write a small embedded system based on Rust and `lilos` crate. The idea is to run object methods concurrently in an asynchronous manner. But I cannot call both methods as each borrows `self` mutably.

What is the Rust way of handling this correctly?

Below code is handling the LED object that should:

1. blink the led
2. check for commands that put it active or not.

```rust
use core::convert::Infallible;
use embedded_hal::digital::v1::OutputPin;

use futures::select_biased;
use futures::FutureExt;
use lilos;
use lilos::exec::PeriodicGate;
use thingbuf as conn;
pub struct Led<'a> {
    pin: &'a mut  dyn OutputPin,
    gate: PeriodicGate,
    recv_cmd: conn::mpsc::Receiver<bool>,
    send_cmd: conn::mpsc::Sender<bool>,
    active: bool,
}
impl<'a> Led<'a> {
    pub fn new(pin: &'a mut dyn OutputPin ) -> Self {
        let (send_cmd, recv_cmd) = conn::mpsc::channel::<bool>(10);
        let gate = PeriodicGate::from(lilos::time::Millis(500));
        Self {
            pin,
            gate,
            send_cmd,
            recv_cmd,
            active: true,
        }
    }

    async fn cmd(&mut self, v: bool) {
        let _ = self.send_cmd.send(v).await;
    }

    async fn blink(&mut self) -> Infallible {
        loop {
            self.gate.next_time().await;
            let _ = self.pin.set_high();
            self.gate.next_time().await;
            let _ = self.pin.set_low();
        }
    }
    async fn on_cmd(&mut self) -> Infallible {
        loop {
            let cmd = self.recv_cmd.recv().await;
            if let Some(x) = cmd {
                self.active = x;
            }
        }
    }
    pub async fn run(&mut self) -> Infallible {
            select_biased!(
                _ = self.blink().fuse() => {},
                _ = self.on_cmd().fuse() => {}
            )
    }
}
```

I tried `Arc`, `RefCell`, `Mutex` which becomes very complicated and didn't compile in the end for the same reasons.

Comment: Which methods do you want to run?

Comment: You can't call two methods which take `&mut self` concurrently, using some synchronization like `Mutex` (so that they can use `&self`) is the way to do it. What have you tried in that direction and what was the error?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman   The method I want to run is the "run()" method which invokes the other 2.

Comment: They don't actually use the same fields, so you can split the struct.

Comment: I tried :  pub async fn run(&mut self) -> Infallible {
        unsafe {
            let mtx = Mutex::new(self);
            let f1 = interrupt::free(|cs| mtx.borrow(cs).blink().fuse());
            let f2 = interrupt::free(|cs| mtx.borrow(cs).on_cmd().fuse());

            loop {
                select_biased!(
                    x = pin!(f1) => return x,
                    y = pin!(f2) => return y,
                )
            }
        }
    }

Comment: @ChayimFriedman at this stage they don't use the same fields , but it is the intention that the active flag influences the blink behaviour.

Comment: It is just a `bool` right? Then you can have most fields split and share an `&AtomicBool` (or `Arc<AtomicBool>`).

Comment: As there is no multi threading involved I find it strange that an Arc or a Mutex is needed. But maybe that is the only option.  Then it still escapes me why this code would compile as it uses the same mutual reference twice also. :     pub async fn run(&mut self) -> Infallible {
        self.blink().await;
        self.on_cmd().await
        
    }

Comment: It is true that it isn't really needed. You're right. You don't need to use atomics. A simple [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.Cell.html) will be enough. `&Cell<bool>` or `Rc<Cell<bool>>`.